# Python is not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I just bought a new notebook and I installed on it Python 3.6 and after restarting it, I tried to open python in CMD using "python" as I used to do in my old laptop but it does not take any effect.
Also I tried with PyCharm console but nothing... 
Somebody knows what to do?

Greetings!

Comment: When you install Python 3.6 on Windows, it asks you whether or not it should add Python to the path. You have to say yes to this for CMD (and possibly PyCharm?) to be able to find Python.

Comment: "does not take any effect" is unhelpfully vague. What actually happens when you type `python` into the command line and hit ENTER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add a system variable so the cmd knows where to look for python interpreter.
check out this link for where you can change the variables.
https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7
Now edit the PATHS variable, at the end add a semicolon and put in the path to your Python interpreter, for example if you havent changed the default it should probably be `C:\Python36`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, you're right.